# How to add vector blur for particles produced by Mantaflow?

Tags: geometry-nodes, particles, fluid-simulation, mantaflow, motion-blur

I'll briefly explain my setup here:

I am trying to render an animation including sand movement produced by a falling object. I have made the simulation using mantaflow as a source for the particle system that will then serve as an instancer for points (Mesh to Points in geometry nodes). I transfered the particle system using the Particle Instance modifier on a different object containing a single vertex (with the previous geo nodes applied to it).

I have also enabled the vector pass output aswell as the Z depth. In compositing nothing seems to be blurred and the vector pass is just a blank image. I am afraid that if I add a Realize Instance after the Mesh to Points node it would break the simulation.

Any clue on how to get vector blur in this case ?

[image]
[image]
[image] [image]